# If $y_t$ is a time series with autocovariance $\gamma$, does $\gamma$ necessarily have to be absolutely-summable?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, stationarity, convergence

If $y_t$ is a time series with autocovariance $\gamma$, does $\gamma$ necessarily have to be absolutely-summable; i.e., ${\sum_{i=\infty}^\infty |\gamma (i)}|<\infty$?
If not, what could be the simplest counter-example?

If we impose the condition that $y_t$ is a stationary series, then does this condition guarantee the absolutely-summability of its autocovariances?

Comment: The time series $y_t=u$ where $u\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ is stationary but its autocovariance function $\gamma(k)=\sigma^2$ is not absolute-summable.

Comment: @JarleTufto Your $y_t$ seems to me normally distributed white noise. For a white noise series, the autocovariances are 0 for k<>0, and $\sigma^2$ for k=0. So, the sum of $\gamma (k)$ is $\sigma^2 + 0 + 0 + 0 = \sigma^2 < \infty$. Hence, your  $y_t$  is absolutely-summable. Am I right?

Comment: No, my example assumes that all $y_t$ (for every $t=0,\pm 1,\dots$) are equal to a single $u$.

Comment: I have 2 questions: 1) You say, $\mu(u)=0<∞$, $\sigma^2(u)=\sigma^2< \infty$, and $\gamma (k)=\sigma^2$. When calculated,
$\gamma (k)=E[(u_t - E(u_t))(u_(t-k)-E(u_(t-k)))] = E[(u_t - 0)(u_(t-k) - 0)]=E[(u_t)(u_(t-k))]$. From here, how could you say $\gamma (k)=\sigma^2$? 2) You say, the example assumes that all $y_t$ (for every $t=0,±1,…$) are equal to a single $u$. But, then, is $y_t$ still a well-defined? For example, for $t=3$, $y_3=u$, but then you assign many $u$ values for single $y_3$. Or, what you mean is that $y_3$ gets a single value from the lottery of $N(0,\sigma^2)$ distribution?

Comment: To me, it seems, you can say $\gamma (k)=\sigma^2$ only for the value of $k=0$!

Comment: Yes to your last comment.

Comment: But then how can one guarantee ${\sum_{i=\infty}^\infty \gamma (i)} = {\sum_{i=\infty}^\infty E[u_t u_{t-i}] }$ to be finite, or infinite in advance?

Comment: You can't.  So this is a simple counter-example showing that $\gamma$ don't have to be absolutely summable.

Comment: Thanks, I got your point now. As for the well-definedness of $y_t$, is my understanding of your definition true:  $y_3$ gets only a single value from the lottery of $N(0,σ^2)$ distribution?

Comment: @JarleTufto You solved the first  part of the question. So, you can add your example in your comments as partial answer for the question.

Comment: I don't see how my example is only a partial answer.  The counter-example is an example of a stationary time series with a autocovariance function that is not absolutely summable so this shows this provides a counter example to the claim you make in your second paragraph of your post.

Comment: @JarleTufto You are right. Your counter example kills both of the paragraphs; i.e., the second paragraph as well. Please write it as full answer. Many thanks, once again.

Comment: @JarleTufto, I changed my opinion on solution to be "full": $\gamma (k)=E[(u_t - E(u_t))(u_(t-k)-E(u_(t-k)))] ]=E[(u_t)(u_(t-k))]$. Now, $\gamma (k)=\sigma^2$ only for $k=0$. Since $E[(u_t)(u_(t-k))]$ could be a function of t, the example you gave cannot even be said to be a stationary series!  In a stationary series, autocovariances cannot be a function of t, may depend only on the time difference separating the observations.

Comment: No, $\mbox{Cov}(y_t,y_{t-k})=\mbox{Cov}(u,u)=\mbox{Var}(u)=\sigma^2$ so it is not a function of $t$.

Comment: @Jarle Your first comment is the perfect answer to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time series $_t=u$ where $\sim (0,\sigma^2)$ is stationary but its autocovariance function $\gamma(k)=\sigma^2$ is not absolute-summable so this provides a counter example to both claims.

Comment: Each component of $y_t=(y_1,y_2,...)$ is a random variable, and all these $y_i$s equals to the random variable $u$. Right?

Comment: Each $y_t$, $t\in\{\dots,-1,0,1,\dots\}$ is a random variable.  Not sure what you mean by $y_t=(y_1,y_2,\dots)$.

Comment: I mean the same thing with that of you. Thanks for your explanations. Now, $Cov(y_t,y_{t−k})=Cov(u,u)=Var(u)=σ^2$ is clear for me.